# c++ string to boost::multiprecision::cpp_int

Tags: c++, boost

How would I convert a string to "boost::multiprecision::cpp_int"?

Additionally, I have a .txt file with 100 numbers each of 50 digits and I use ifstream to read them line by line into a string array. How can I convert each string from the array into a `cpp_int`, then add all the 100 numbers and get the sum?

Comment: `cpp_int i("123456789012345678901234567890");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a single string, use the `cpp_int`constructor: `cpp_int tmp("123");`.

For the text file case, read each number in a loop as a `std::string` via `std::getline`, then emplace back in a `std::vector<cpp_int>`. Then use the latter to compute your sum. Example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int main()
{    
    std::vector<cpp_int> v;
    std::fstream fin("in.txt");

    std::string num;
    while(std::getline(fin, num))
    {
        v.emplace_back(num);
    }
    cpp_int sum = 0;
    for(auto&& elem: v)
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl; // just to make sure we read correctly
        sum += elem;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;
}
```

PS: you may do it without a `std::vector`, via a temporary `cpp_int` that you construct inside the loop and assign it to `sum`:

```
std::string num;
cpp_int sum = 0;
while(std::getline(fin, num))
{
    cpp_int tmp(num);
    sum += tmp;
}
std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but i already found a better way(for my use). I just cast using: cpp_int[i] = cpp_int(mystring[i]); // I don't know if it's better but it works.

Comment: @sLowDowN This is exactly I meant, i.e. create and copy. String can be assigned to a variable, so you don't have to hardcode the value.

Comment: @sLowDowN It's the same thing basically. I wrote the temporary explicitly for clarity, but of course you can just do `sum += cpp_int{num};` inside the loop.